# Add column data value labels in Google Drive Spreadsheet chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Is there an (easy) way to add data-value labels to the columns of a Google Drive Spreadsheet column chart? Either fixed or mouse-over?

I have the charts already made, and would not like to have to define them again.
So I'm basically looking to alter the default behaviour of the existing charts.

The spreadsheet and charts are not (yet) for publishing, only for sharing directly.

Nick

Comment: Did you ever find out if this is possible somehow?

Comment: Nope. And I've not been active on Google Spreadsheets for some time. 
I hope this simple and essential requirement is solved by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets embedded charts have text annotations. To use them for values, you could use [TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) function. I.E. assume that you have a two column chart, then add a third column for annotations. Add the following formula

`=TEXT(A2,"0")`

then fill down as necessary.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y2mXH07__6u5wAO6z4RTINkO0yrmZKm6m235tG_4LT0/edit?usp=sharing)

**References**
[Adding annotations to a chart - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2382813?hl=en)